# Laravel 4 Custom Validator throws BadMethodCallException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm building my first Laravel 4 application, and attempting to extend the Validator class to simply check if a path exists. Following the [official instruction](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules), I've come up with this:

app/libraries/CustomValidator.php:

```
class CustomValidator extends Illuminate\Validation\Validator {
    public function validatePathExists($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
        return is_dir($value);
    }
}

Validator::resolver(function() {
    return new CustomValidator;
});
```

In the controller (stripped down a bit):

```
    $rules = array(
        'path'      => 'required|path_exists',
    );

    $v = Validator::make(Input::get(), $rules);
```

This code throws a `BadMethodCallException`, with this message: `Method [validatePathExists] does not exist.`

I've added `app/libraries` into `composer.json` autoload:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/libraries"
    ]
},
```

and run `composer dump-autoload` of course. In fact, there's a Helper.php under the same `app/libraries` directory, which is working fine.

Also, in `app/start/global.php` (by the way, I don't quite understand why we have to (?) have the same autostart registers in two places).

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(

    app_path().'/commands',
    app_path().'/controllers',
    app_path().'/models',
    app_path().'/database/seeds',
    app_path().'/libraries',

));
```

Still the error occurs. Any idea? 
Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: You don't have any of the dependencies being injected into your custom resolver. Take a look at the docs again.

Comment: @JosephSilber No, I don't even think the custom resolver is being used. I just noticed that the dependencies aren't there, so that's where I'd start.

Comment: @JasonLewis Sorry, I don't get what you mean. I should've added that this is the first time I work with Laravel.

Comment: If you look at the documentation that you linked to when you register a resolver you need to give your custom `Validator` class some dependencies. From the docs: `return new CustomValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);` Don't forget to include these variables as parameters to your closure.

Comment: @JasonLewis Actually I've tried adding them, to the same exception:

`Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages) {
    return new CustomValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
});`

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you ever find a solution to this problem? I had a similar problem yesterday where everything was set up properly, but I was using `"file_exists," . $path` instead of `"file_exists:" . $path. Not quite the same problem as yours, but I'm still interested if you figured yours out.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't register your Validator Resolver correctly.

Compare the syntax below to your code.

```
Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
{
    return new CustomValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I answered @JasonLewis above that I've already tried this syntax with no success.